# 20.04 add apt-key when installing

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, mirrors

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.4 Server and it forces me to do an update on install as it has an internet connection. (You have the option not to when it doesn't)

My problem is that I need to install and update from a package mirror that is signed by keys that not normally trusted.

Is there a way I can add the mirror and public key at install time?

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 (and older), and Ubuntu Server 18.04 (and older), this seems like a classic use case for a [preseed file](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed).

Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 (and newer) and Ubuntu Server 20.04 (and newer) use a different installer. Preseed files have been replaced with [cloud-init files](https://cloud-init.io/).

Both preseed and cloud-init are highly customizable.

Comment: I don't see how that will help.

Comment: Your question specified that you want your custom repo *as part of the install*. You do that using Preseed or Cloud-init. It is obviously much simpler to customize a system if it's *not* part of the install, but (for example) a script afterward. If we've misunderstood, then please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: You can specify the mirror during install, I'm asking if there is a way to add the the key the mirror is signed by during install.

Comment: No, you cannot add a custom key/repo to the installer. Yes, you can install a custom key/repo to the installed system, and install specific packages during the install. Using a preseed file or cloud-init file is the normal way of doing that.